# How can I break down parts of a string and add it to a list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, split

I have the following string

```
var tString = "user@Name:Alex; //*[local-name() = 'Alex']" ;
```

I have a List of a type named `UserModel` which has two properties `ElementID` and `Expression`

```
List<UserModel> myUserList = new List <UserModel>();
```

I am trying to write some code which I can break the above string such that in myUserList to `ElementID` a value like `Alex` from the part  `user@Name:Alex` of the string can be added and to the `Expression` I can add the part  `//*[local-name() = 'Alex']` of the string .

Would really appreciate some advice on this . How can I do this in c#

Comment: Typo, or why did you mention ElementID twice?

Comment: Typo , I corrected it :)

Comment: Why a List of usermodel? When you split the string with `;` ... second item would be your expression. Split the first item with `:` and you get a name in the second item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regular expression for this

```
var tString = "user@Name:Alex; //*[local-name() = 'Alex']" ;
var regEx = new Regex("user@Name:(?<elementID>.+); (?<expression>.+)");
var match = regEx.Match(tString);

var elementID = match.Groups["elementID"].Value;
var expression = match.Groups["expression"].Value;

Console.WriteLine(elementID);
Console.WriteLine(expression);
```

See it in action:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rZH6RB

Just in case you don't know how to fill your list with the above code, here an example, that uses the result of the regular expression to create a new instance of `UserModel` and to fill a list with this new instance.

```
var tString = "user@Name:Alex; //*[local-name() = 'Alex']" ;
var regEx = new Regex("user@Name:(?<elementID>.+); (?<expression>.+)");
var match = regEx.Match(tString);

var newUserModel = new UserModel() { 
                       ElementID = match.Groups["elementID"].Value, 
                       Expression = match.Groups["expression"].Value 
                   };

var myUserList = new List<UserModel>();
myUserList.Add(newUserModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use simple `String.Split`

```
public class UserModel 
{
  public string ElementID { get; set; }
  public string Expression { get; set; }
}

    var tString = "user@Name:Alex; //*[local-name() = 'Alex']";
    var stringParts = tString.Split("//*", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var um = new UserModel();
    um.ElementID = stringParts.FirstOrDefault()?.Replace("user@Name:", string.Empty).Trim().TrimEnd(';');
    um.Expression = $"//*{stringParts.LastOrDefault()?.Trim()}";
```

Of course, you'd have to be somewhat sure in the input sanity.